# jquery else condition inside onscroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, scroll, conditional-statements

I have a problem in animation in onscroll event.

The if condition works very well when I scroll down and div shows without any problem, but when I scroll up, the else condition does not work, so the div doesn't hide and it is still shown.

This is the code:

```
$(function () {

    'use strict';

    var myDiv1 = $('div'),
        div1Top = (myDiv1.offset().top) / 2;

    $(window).on('scroll', function () {

        var docScrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

        if (docScrollTop >= div1Top) {

            $('div').animate({opacity: '1'}, 800);

        } else {

            $('div').css('opacity', '0');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be *exactly* what you're trying to do, but I think it's in the right ballpark:

```html
<html>

  <style>
    div {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    .animated_div {
      background-color: green;
      position: absolute;
      top: 2000px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .placeholder {
      position: absolute;
      top:4000px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="animated_div"></div>  <!--The div that will actually be animated-->
    <div class="placeholder"></div>   <!--This is just something below the animated DIV, so that you can scroll below the animated DIV -->
  </body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

      'use strict';

      var myDiv1 = $('.animated_div');

      // Start animating the div relative to its middle
      var div1Middle = myDiv1.offset().top + myDiv1.height() / 2;

      // Keep track of whether the animated_div is displayed or not
      var myDiv1Shown = false;    

      $(window).on('scroll', function () {

          var docScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();               // Top of the window in page coordinates
          var docScrollBottom = docScrollTop+$(window).height();  // Bottom of the window in page coordinates

          if (div1Middle > docScrollTop && div1Middle < docScrollBottom && !myDiv1Shown) {
              // The div middle is within view and it's not already shown, so we need to show it
              myDiv1Shown = true;
              myDiv1.animate({opacity: '1'}, 800);
          } else if ((div1Middle > docScrollBottom || div1Middle < docScrollTop) && myDiv1Shown) {
              // The div middle is out of view and it's shown, so we need to hide it
              myDiv1Shown = false;
              myDiv1.animate({opacity: '0'}, 800);
          }

      });

    });

  </script>     

</html>
```

This changes the div opacity to 1 when it's in view and changes it to 0 when it's out of view. It's considered in-view if its vertical middle is in view.

If what you want to do is essentially fade-in the div when the user scrolls it into view and then fade-out the div when the user scrolls it out of view, you might consider this as an alternative:

```html
<html>

  <style>
    div {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    .animated_div {
      background-color: green;
      position: absolute;
      top: 2000px;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .placeholder {
      position: absolute;
      top:4000px;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="animated_div"></div>  <!--The div that will actually be animated-->
    <div class="placeholder"></div>   <!--This is just something below the animated DIV, so that you can scroll below the animated DIV -->
  </body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

      'use strict';

      var myDiv1 = $('.animated_div');

      var div1Top = myDiv1.offset().top;
      var div1Height = myDiv1.height();
      var div1Bottom = div1Top + div1Height;

      $(window).on('scroll', function () {

          var docScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();               // Top of the window in page coordinates
          var docScrollBottom = docScrollTop+$(window).height();  // Bottom of the window in page coordinates

          // Calculate fraction of div on page
          var topOffPage = Math.max(0, docScrollTop - div1Top);
          var bottomOffPage = Math.max(0, div1Bottom - docScrollBottom);
          var fractionOnPage = Math.max(0, div1Height - topOffPage - bottomOffPage)/div1Height;

          myDiv1.css('opacity', fractionOnPage);

      });

    });

  </script>     

</html>
```

The snippet immediately above sets the opacity of the div to be the fraction of it that is in view (considering only the vertical dimension). So if the entire DIV is on-screen, it's fully opaque. If only half of it is onscreen (with half of it either above the scroll top or below the scroll bottom), then the opacity is 0.5, and so on. If the div is large relative to the screen, then this could cause problems. For instance, if you have a 1000px div, and people are viewing the page with a viewport of height 500px, then the div will only ever be 50% opaque at most. But you can adapt it as necessary to fit your circumstances.